# Which Studio will help to enroll new customer through Social Media Sites

Tags: marketing-cloud, contact, social-studio, advertising-studio

I have a requirement where we do not have any existing customer data, but we want to use Social Media sites to enroll new customer in our Account. Which Studio will help us achieve this task? Social Studio or Advertising Studio?

Answer (score 2):

You will need Advertising Studio’s [lead capture feature](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_ads_lead_capture.htm&type=5&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null). This will allow you to create lead ads, and have the fields submitted directly into data extensions.

However, before you send out emails to these new contacts, ensure they are provided with an appropriate subscriber key, as they otherwise will be created with their email address as subscriber key, which is not recommended.

Comment: We are creating a registration portal on Community Cloud and would like to share the url of the registration page through these Social Sites. Is Advertising Studio still recommend for it?

Comment: If you don’t need to target existing contacts, or create segments of their lookalikes, Advertising Studio will not be needed.

Comment: Thanks Lukas 

Comment: You’re welcome @LijoJohns - remember to accept/upvote